# PyQt5 : How to do it? Completed the first command and updated the graphics. and repeat the same until the result is true

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qt5, qt-designer

I'm going to make the blue boxes move to the right one by one. is an anime Until reaching the location of the last box?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wSeNF.jpg)

Someone advised me to use QTimer but I still don't understand how to use it so the effect is no different, guide me please.

code i wrote when we press the start button It will finish all the work first and then update the graphics.
Code:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton, 
QLabel, QGridLayout
from PyQt5.QtGui import QFont
import time


class UI_main(QWidget):     

  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.Main = QWidget()
    self.Main.setFixedSize(400, 400)

    self.Main.setWindowTitle('PyQt5')

    self.pushStart = QPushButton('Start', self.Main)
    self.pushStart.setGeometry(50, 50, 120, 90)

    self.pushClose = QPushButton('Close', self.Main)
    self.pushClose.setGeometry(250, 250, 100, 100)
    self.ui_Block()
    self.pushStart.clicked.connect(self.push_Start)
    self.pushClose.clicked.connect(self.Main.close)
    self.Main.show()

  def ui_Block(self):
    num = [0, 1, 2, 3]
    self.GridLayout = QGridLayout()
    self.Main.setLayout(self.GridLayout)
    self.numBlock(num)

  def numBlock(self, num):
    self.num = num
    for i in range(len(self.num)):
        self.GridLayout.addWidget(Label_Block(self.num[i]), 0, i)

    self.Main.setLayout(self.GridLayout)    

  def push_Start(self):
    i = 0
    self.num = self.Function(i)

  def Function(self, i):
    self.i = i
    self.i = i + 1
    print(i)
    num, self.i = self.Function2(self.i)
    print("2s")
    time.sleep(2)
    self.numBlock(num)
    self.i = self.i + 1
    num, self.i = self.Function3(self.i)
    print("2s")
    time.sleep(2)
    self.numBlock(num)
    self.i = self.i + 1
    num, self.i = self.Function4(self.i)
    print("2s")
    time.sleep(2)
    self.numBlock(num)

  def Function2(self, i):
    block = [0, 1, 2, 3]
    self.i = i
    print(self.i)
    if self.i == 1:
        block[0] = 1
        block[1] = 0
        block[2] = 2
        block[3] = 3
        self.i = self.i+1
    return block, i

  def Function3(self, i):
    block = [0, 1, 2, 3]
    self.i = i
    print(self.i)
    if self.i == 2:
        block[0] = 1
        block[1] = 2
        block[2] = 0
        block[3] = 3
        self.i = self.i + 1
    return block, i

  def Function4(self, i):
    block = [0, 1, 2, 3]
    self.i = i
    print(self.i)
    if self.i == 3:
        block[0] = 1
        block[1] = 2
        block[2] = 3
        block[3] = 0
        self.i = self.i + 1
    return block, i

class Label_Block(QLabel):
  def __init__(self, block_):
    super().__init__()
    self.block_ = block_
    self.setFixedSize(80, 80)
    font = QFont()

    font.setPointSize(30)
    font.setBold(True)
    self.setFont(font)
    if self.block_ == 0:
        self.setStyleSheet("background-color:blue;border-radius:10px;")
        print('block: ', block_)
    elif self.block_ == 1:
        self.setStyleSheet("background-color:red;border-radius:10px;")
        print('block: ', block_)
    elif self.block_ == 2:
        self.setStyleSheet("background-color:green;border-radius:10px;")
        print('block: ', block_)
    elif self.block_ == 3:
        self.setStyleSheet("background-color:yellow;border-radius:10px;")
        print('block: ', block_)

if __name__ == "__main__":
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
ui = UI_main()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: First of all, we cannot answer questions that broad or extremely vague, so please take your time to follow the [tour], read [ask] and review the [checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648). Then, please consider that StackOverflow is not a tutorial or how to website: we can only answer to specific, detailed questions. It seems clear that you're still in the process of learning basic aspects of programming (including OOP, which is a step even further), so I'd recommend you to be patient and don't try to skip steps in that learning. Programming is hugely fun, but it's not an immediate one.

Comment: I'm very sorry, I'm in a little too much of a hurry. Thank you very much for your advice.

Comment: I'm sorry, but SO is not a help service. Some questions get answers even **years** after they've been asked. If you're in a hurry, then SO is probably not what you're looking for, at least right now. Programming is considered by many a form of art, and, as such, requires *a lot* of patience, experience and learning; things that require months, years or even decades. If you truly believe that you can become a programmer and/or solve your code issues in a matter of hours, you are either misunderstanding what programming is (but that's probably not your fault), or, at least, on the wrong website.

Comment: I understand what you want to tell me I will study more.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example that uses portions of your code and implements a QTimer that sends singleShot signals after 1 second to update the labels position in a QHBoxLayout...  See inline notes for more details.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *

class UI_main(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__() 
        # There is no need for a self.Main = QWidget since you are subclassing QWidget
        self.setFixedSize(400, 400)
        self.setWindowTitle('PyQt5')
        self.grid_layout = QGridLayout(self)
        self.pushStart = QPushButton('Start', self)
        self.pushStart.setGeometry(50, 50, 120, 90)
        self.pushClose = QPushButton('Close', self)
        self.pushClose.setGeometry(250, 250, 100, 100)
        self.grid_layout.addWidget(self.pushStart, 0, 0)
        self.grid_layout.addWidget(self.pushClose, 0, 1)
        self.pushStart.clicked.connect(self.push_start)
        self.pushClose.clicked.connect(self.close)

        # I am Using a horizontal layout that only holds the labels
        # to make it easier to pop labels off the layout and insert them back in
        self.hlayout = QHBoxLayout()   

        # iterate the list of colors to create each of the labels
        colors = ["red", "blue", "green", "yellow"]  
        self.labels = []   # save references to each of the labels.
        for color in colors:
            label = Label_Block(color)
            self.labels.append(label)
            self.hlayout.addWidget(label)
        
        # set the number of times you want to move the boxes over by one
        self.counter = len(self.labels) - 1   
        
        
        self.grid_layout.addLayout(self.hlayout,1,0,1,2)
        self.timer = QTimer() 

    def push_start(self):
        # when the counter reaches 0 stop and reset counter
        if self.counter == 0:  
            self.counter = len(self.labels) - 1
            return
        # otherwise pop off the last label in the layout and insert it back
        # into the layout at the front.  Then reduce the counter by 1.
        # and emit a singleShot timer with a 1 second timeout connected to 
        # this same method.
        count = self.hlayout.count()
        item = self.hlayout.takeAt(count-1)
        self.hlayout.insertWidget(0, item.widget())
        self.counter -= 1
        self.timer.singleShot(1000, self.push_start)  # after 1000 ms / 1 sec


class Label_Block(QLabel):

  def __init__(self, color):
    super().__init__()
    self.setFixedSize(80, 80)
    self.setStyleSheet(f"background-color:{color};border-radius:10px;")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ui = UI_main()
    ui.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```